# Qt: Creating a directory via project file

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm trying to have my compiled language files copied into my output directory during the build process. I've got the copying down, but not the creating of the directory. After a lot of googling I came up with this:

```
LANGDIR = $$OUT_PWD
win32:CONFIG(debug, release|debug):LANGDIR = $$LANGDIR/debug/lang
win32:CONFIG(release, release|debug):LANGDIR = $$LANGDIR/release/lang

makeLang.commands += $${QMAKE_MKDIR} $$shell_path($${LANGDIR})
first.depends = $(first) makeLang
export(first.depends)
export(makeLang.commands)
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += first makeLang
```

This does the job for the most part, however, when the directory lang already exists, the build process fails. I know `QMAKE_CHK_DIR_EXISTS` exists, but I have no clue how to use that as a conditional. I figured perhaps it's something like this `!$${QMAKE_CHK_DIR_EXISTS} $$shell_path($${LANGDIR}) : $${QMAKE_MKDIR} $$shell_path($${LANGDIR})` but that just crashes jom.exe; didn't really expect that to work anyways.

I'm also open to suggestions for better ways to do what I'm trying to do. Ideally the whole thing should be platform independent so I can have artifacts generated in my CI pipeline that contain the language files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `QMAKE_MKDIR_CMD` which creates the directory only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, this worked, although it should be noted that it's not as simple as replacing one with the other. Instead, I needed to use this line: `makeLang.commands += $$sprintf($${QMAKE_MKDIR_CMD}, $$shell_path($${LANGDIR}))` to get the command to take my parameter. this seems to work flawlessly now.